# Handling blur click and focus events of dropdown input suggestion lists in react

Tags: reactjs

I have implemented an input text box which shows suggestion lists on focus event

I have also added a blur event which makes the list disappear

My problem is when the user clicks on an item in the list the blur event of the input text box fires before the click event of the list item and the click event of the list item never fires

```js
class SearchBar extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { queryString: '', showSearchHistory: false };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSearchHistoryItemClick = this.handleSearchHistoryItemClick.bind(this);
    this.handleFocus = this.handleFocus.bind(this);
    this.handleBlur = this.handleBlur.bind(this);
    this.handleSearchClick = this.handleSearchClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({ queryString: event.target.value });
  }
  handleSearchHistoryItemClick(item){
    console.log("handleSearchHistoryItemClick: ",item);
    this.setState({ queryString: item, showSearchHistory: false });
  }
  handleFocus(){
    this.setState({ showSearchHistory: true });
  }
  handleBlur(){
    this.setState({ showSearchHistory: false });
  }
  handleSearchClick(){
    this.props.onSearchClick(this.state.queryString);
  }

  render() {
    const searchHistory = this.props.searchHistory && this.props.searchHistory.map( (historyItem, index) => {
      return <li key={index} onClick={()=>this.handleSearchHistoryItemClick(historyItem)}>{historyItem}</li>
      
    } );
    return (
      <section className="searchBar">
        <div onFocus={this.handleFocus} onBlur={this.handleBlur} >
        <input className="searchBox" placeholder="Search movie.." type="text" value={this.state.queryString} onChange={this.handleChange} />
        { searchHistory.length &&
          <ul className={this.state.showSearchHistory ? "searchHistoryList show" : "searchHistoryList" } >
            {searchHistory}
          </ul>
        }
        </div>
        <button className="searchButton" onClick={this.handleSearchClick}>Search</button>
      </section>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Usually the way to handle it is using `mousedown` rather than click, since the event order is `mousedown, blue, mouseup, click`. If you check the other stack overflow posts in this google search you'll see something JS solutions and some explanations of the reason behind the issue: https://www.google.com.au/search?q=javascript+click+before+blur&oq=javascript+click+before+blur

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried pushing the blur to the back of the event loop?

```
handleBlur(){
  setTimeout(
    () => this.setState({ showSearchHistory: false }),
    0
  );
}
```